# How is the Type of a Cell used in HBase?

Tags: java, hbase, cell

I was reading of a [Cell in HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/Cell.html) and saw that the value is unique given row, column family, column qualifier, timestamp, and type.

I knew the first 4 but didn't know nothing about that `type` as I always known that HBase stores everything as byte array. Then I discovered it is not the type of the value but `The byte representation of the KeyValue.TYPE of this cell: one of Put, Delete, etc`. Link to the code [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/e6e52cd80f4ba26b196e2d20cd84ba167b303475/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.java#L235).

- Is it the value of the *CRUD* operation that caused the state of that `Cell`?
  Why does HBase stores that?
- How can a type of a `Cell` be `delete`? Shouldn't the Cell be eliminated after the delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the fact that HBase does not delete cell immediately, instead it puts a tombstone marker that indicates that cell is deleted. Scans and get operations will ignore the cell if they see this marker. After major compaction all these cells will be physically deleted.

Comment: Is it useful to give the access to this information instead of just using the tombstone and this field under the hood?

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo it is possible to create a scan programmatically that will read all cells including deleted. that's why it's available with api

Comment: I see. I just don't see the use case of retrieving the cell that are deleted from your application/business layer but not physically on HBase and they are just waiting for the compaction to be really removed. I was just think about a use case where someone needs that information instead of being managed only from HBase itself.

BTW this answer my question, accepting it.

Comment: @AndreaBergonzo e.g. you deleted more than you expected by mistake and want to retrieve it back before compaction